# HTML 5 validations disappear if I use type = button

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form (note that this is only one segment of the form, there are 2 more):

```
<form action="index.php?s=2468" id="multiphase" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<label class="form-controlradio"> 
<input id="1-0" type="radio" class="custom" name="answer_16e0807d-5612-11e5-824b-22000a699fb3" required="" value="EPOS programma">
EPOS programma </label>
<label class="form-controlradio"> <input id="1-1" type="radio" class="custom" name="answer_16e0807d-5612-11e5-824b-22000a699fb3" required="" value="Analogue Cash Register">
Analogue Cash Register </label> 
<label class="form-controlradio"> <input id="1-2" type="radio" class="custom" name="answer_16e0807d-5612-11e5-824b-22000a699fb3" required="" value="EPOS system">
EPOS system </label>
<input type="button" value="Next" name="" onclick="processPhase1()" class="btn btn-primary" id="multiphase-element-13">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The form is devided in 3 step using `<div id="phase1">`, `<div id="phase2">` and `<div id="phase3">`. I use JS to display or hide the div's , this is the code:

```
function processPhase1(){
    var val1 = getRadioVal( document.getElementById('multiphase'), 'answer_16e0807d-5612-11e5-824b-22000a699fb3' );
    var val2 = getRadioVal( document.getElementById('multiphase'), 'answer_4f14f466-5612-11e5-824b-22000a699fb3' );
    if(val1.length > 1 && val2.length > 1){
        _("phase1").style.display = "none";
        _("phase2").style.display = "block";
        _("progressBar").style.width = "33%";
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to use `input type="button"` and if I use this the HTML 5 validations disappear. I know that there is a hackish way to make it work but I'm not very god at JS

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "required" in your input.

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: I have the required="" in my input

Comment: required without quotes, my friend. I hope this example help you: http://www.html5-tutorials.org/form-validation/validating-email/

Comment: I doesn't have quotes, anly in copy/paste the quotes appear.

Answer (score 1):

The button input type will not submit the parent form. You'd need to use input type="submit". However, with a bit of Javascript, you should be able to achieve the validation you require:

```
  document.querySelector('input[type=button]').onclick = function() {
       var i = document.querySelector(".custom");
       var f = document.getElementById("multiphase");
       if (i.checkValidity() == false) {
          f.innerHTML = f.innerHTML + i.validationMessage;
       } else {
          f.submit();
      }
  }
```

Comment: I have one problem with your code "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null"

Comment: I'm using chrome and in the example the alet appears but not in the HTML5 format like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2234377/img/required_attrib.png)

Comment: One more thing  if I wrap in `window.onload = function(){ //your code }` the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null` is gone but the button is not working any more

Comment: I wraped `window.onload = function(){
document.querySelector('input[type=button]').onclick = function() {
       var i = document.querySelector(".custom");
       var f = document.getElementById("multiphase");
       if (i.checkValidity() == false) {
          f.innerHTML = f.innerHTML + i.validationMessage;
       } 
  }
}` now the alert is working but it is only a txt under the submit button, it doesn't look like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2234377/img/required_attrib.png)

Comment: You will need to style the notifications yourself using CSS. The default HTML5 input notifications can only be displayed when a user clicks a **submit** button.